# Ftp list directory behind a http proxy

Tags: .net, ftp

I'm trying to list the files from a ftp address using FtpWebRequest class

```
    private IEnumerable<ResourceInfo> EnumerateResources(Stream stream)
    {
        StreamReader reader = new StreamReader(stream);
        string line = null;
        while ((line = reader.ReadLine()) != null)
        {
            yield return new ResourceInfo(this, line);
        }
    }

    public override IReadOnlyList<ResourceInfo> GetResources()
    {
        FtpWebRequest req = (FtpWebRequest)WebRequest.Create(Url);
        req.Method = WebRequestMethods.Ftp.ListDirectory;

        req.Credentials = Credentials;
        using (var resp = (FtpWebResponse)req.GetResponse())
        {
            using (var stream = resp.GetResponseStream())
            {
                return EnumerateResources(stream).ToReadOnly();
            }
        }
    }
```

This works ok in most cases.
But when i'm behind an HTTP proxy the content of the response stream contains a HTML page
that lists the files inside **a** tags. Is there any elegant way to treat this or should i just try to parse the HTML by hand.

Answer (score 0):

You should probably look into using the [HTML Agility Pack](http://www.codeplex.com/htmlagilitypack). But if you provide exactly the format maybe something simpler can be crafted.

Comment: i have already developed a hack to extract the data from the proxy generated HTML. i was just wandering if there is a more elegant way to do it